# For loop with generic collection fails to compile in Java 7

Tags: java, generics, types, osgi, java-7

Maybe someone can explain the behaviour below. I know there were some generic type-handling changes from Java 6 to 7, but I couldn't find one to explain this.

This is happening with this library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.felix.framework</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And the following demonstration code:

```
import org.apache.felix.framework.util.manifestparser.ManifestParser;

ManifestParser manifestParser = new ManifestParser(null, null, null, null);
for (Capability capability : manifestParser.getCapabilities()) {
    capability.toString();
}

// where the signature of getCapabilities() is:
// public List<Capability> getCapabilities() { return m_capabilities; }
// and there are no other methods with similar signatures or names
```

This demo code compiles just fine with JDK 6 (x86, 1.6.0_45, 32-bit), but fails to compile with JDK 7 (x86, 1.7.0_25, 32-bit, same host):

```
// line number matches the for loop
java: incompatible types
required: org.apache.felix.framework.capabilityset.Capability
found:    java.lang.Object
```

After some head scratching, I have a workaround but no explanation. The following modification to the demo code compiles with JDK 7:

```
ManifestParser manifestParser = new ManifestParser(null, null, null, null);
List<Capability> capabilities = manifestParser.getCapabilities();
for (Capability capability : capabilities) {
    capability.toString();
}
```

Why is this?

Comment: Can you show us the `ManifestParser` class declaration. For whatever reason this fails, I don't know why, but there is no such changes in generics from Java 6 to Java 7, which can make this fail. Either it will fail in both, or none.

Comment: Did you recompile the code after sdk change?

Comment: It probably has something to do with a compilation problem or SDK settings because I have try it with JDK 7 and the code compile without any warning.

Comment: @promanski I recompiled all my code, but I didn't recompile 3rd party libraries such as the one felix framework. I generally do not do this and have never run into this issue before.

Comment: @RohitJain I've looked at `ManifestParser` and couldn't see anything strange. Their source jar is available in maven central. Incidentally, this jar is an OSGi bundle, built using JDK 1.6.0_17.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeBond I've tried changing source compatibility levels between 1.6 and 1.7, tried maven-compile-plugin 2.5.1 vs 3.1, tried straight javac, etc. Always the same error. Which JDK7 did you use?

Comment: I have use the JDK 1.7.0_25 64-bit.

Comment: Java 7 wouldn't have made a change to generics that breaks working code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [How to compile mavenized OSGi 4.3 bundle with OpenJDK 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911231/how-to-compile-mavenized-osgi-4-3-bundle-with-openjdk-7)

Because of the OSGi classes in that felix jar, you cannot use it to compile against with Java 7.

Comment: This isn't about the OSGi classes, but about the Felix classes which could've been compiled with a sane `-target`. EDIT: Nope, turns you're right, the Felix classes don't have generic signatures either. So the problem is that the method does in fact return `List` as far as the IDE is concerned, but navigating to its source in the IDE is misleading.

Comment: Write once, compile everywhere.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this explanation. If you look at my second code snippet, you can see that the same class compiles fine in Java 7 when I move the getCapabilities() function call out of the for statement. On the other hand, I do believe there is something funny with this library.

Comment: The classes in the felix jar are compiled with the -target jsr14 compiler setting. This generates version 48 (Java 1.4) class files which include generic signature information. Java 5 and 6 javac understood this odd arrangement just fine. But in Java 7, support for this was removed. Java 7 javac will ignore any generic signature information in a version 48 class file. So the short answer is that you cannot use Java 7 javac to compile against the felix jar and use generics.

Comment: BTW, the felix classes DO have generic signatures:


$ javap -v org.apache.felix.framework.capabilityset.Capability
Compiled from "Capability.java"
public interface org.apache.felix.framework.capabilityset.Capability
  SourceFile: "Capability.java"
  minor version: 0
  major version: 48


const #25 = Asciz ()Ljava/util/List<Lorg/apache/felix/framework/capabilityset/Directive;>;;
const #29 = Asciz ()Ljava/util/List<Lorg/apache/felix/framework/capabilityset/Attribute;>;;
const #31 = Asciz ()Ljava/util/List<Ljava/lang/String;>;;

Comment: It would be much better if version 48 with generics throwed `ClassFormatError` instead of this. Using an undocumented unsupported compiler flag is simply evil. These classes should be simply considered invalid and ill-formed and should be blacklisted.

Comment: It is not evil. It is not bad. They are valid class files. Class files can any attributes include generic signature attributes. It is just that Oracle decided that in Java 7, javac would cease to recognize generic signature attributes in class files with versions prior to 49.

Comment: This is because there is nothing stopping you from modifying class files and inserting any arbitrary attributes, including some that may resemble malformed generics. They will be simply ignored by a 1.4 JVM. But in version >= 49, they would cause a `GenericSignatureFormatError` upon reflection. However, version 48 does not have generics, so you should never get a `GenericSignatureFormatError`. The solution for this problem is simple: Version 48 does not have generics as they never did. Period. The fact that Java 5 and Java 6 accepted them as generics is a bug, and not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that there is no classpath problem, like different versions of the same class in the classpath? This could be possible if you have in the classpath two versions of the same class, one for java 1.4 returning `List` and one for java 5+ returning `List<Capability>`.

Comment: Maven can create very strange and annoying problems if it somehow get to add different versions of the same dependency more than once. It supposedly should manage that, but there are some loopholes (e.g. a JAR file present with two or more groupIds/artifactIds). Further, its ordering is not necessarily consistent between different JDK's.

Comment: Can you post your entire pom.xml?

Comment: Near as I can tell the earlier versions of Felix returned `ICapability[]` from that method, which [wouldn't have complained about the type being `Object`](http://ideone.com/6UWGzX).

Comment: I'm sure there is no classpath issue, since I can reproduce this issue with only just this library on the classpath.